# Set element onclick from JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick, typescript

I have some code which generates HTML with something like this:

```ts
function foo(onclick:string):HTMLElement {
    return parseHTML('<input type="button" onclick="' + escapeHTML(onclick) + '" />');
}
```

which I want to migrate to code like this:

```ts
function foo(onclick:string):HTMLElement {
   var input = document.createElement('input');
   input.type = 'button';
   input.onclick = onclick; // <= is this correct?
   return input;
}
```

Besides the fact that I should be using a real JavaScript function instead of a string of code, what is the correct way to set the `onclick` attribute using the passed JavaScript string so that it works the same way as it did when generating HTML with the `onclick` attribute?

edit:

The `input.onclick` property the code above is setting is supposed to be a real JavaScript function object, not a string of JavaScript (according to [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)) so the code above is not correct.

I am trying to change the implementation of `foo()` *without* needing the change the usages. They need to be able to continue passing in a string of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to convert the JavaScript string into a function object with a single parameter using the `Function` constructor:

```
function foo(onclick:string):HTMLElement {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'button';
    input.onclick = new Function('event', onclick);
    return input;
}
```

This gives the passed JavaScript code the exact same environment as though it were written in the `onclick="..."` attribute in HTML:

- The `event` variable will be set to the appropriate `Event` object
- The `arguments` will contain a single argument which is the `Event` object
- The `this` object will be the HTML element itself
- The code will run in it's own scope with the global scope next in the scope chain

The solution comes from http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/

This would also work:

```
// ...
input.onclick = (1,eval)('(function(event){' + onclick + '})');
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

It is better to attach handlers using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) as this supports multiple handlers for the same event and can be used to listen for any event *type* (even custom ones like *"myAwesomeNewEvent"*)

```
input.addEventListener('click', onclick);
```

Comment: `addEventListener()` expects a function object, not a JavaScript string. I need `foo()` to continue to take string of JavaScript, I can't update the usages.

Answer (score -1):

onclick parameter must be function object

```
function foo(onclick){
   var input = document.createElement('button');
   input.type = 'button';
   input.onclick = onclick; // <= is this correct?
   return input;
}
```

And then you can use

```
var a = function(){alert("Test");};
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(foo(a));
```

Comment: `node.append` is _undefined_, you probably want `.appendChild`. `document.getElementById('#val')` is `null`, you probably want `'val'`. OP also states _"I should be using a real JavaScript function instead of a string"_

Comment: Thanks Paul S. Sorry i am wrong with JQuery syntax :)

Comment: I need `foo()` to continue to take string of JavaScript; I can't update the usages to pass a function object.